# How to group adjacent xml elements with xslt 2.0 or 3.0?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I need to adjust below xslt code to wrap the elements that are adjacent to any p whose name attributes include "level_" as a child to the preceding p, which gets transformed to li tags in the output xml.

Here is the source xml:

```
    <root>
    <header>Header text</header>
    <p name="paragraph">Normal Paragraph</p>
    <p name="level_1">Value 1</p>
    <p name="level_1">Value 2 table</p>
    <table frame="all" rowsep="1" colsep="1"   
    id="table_whs_jmk_hzb">
    <title>table1</title>
    <tgroup cols="2" align="center">
    <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="1*"/>
    <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="1*"/>
    <thead>
    <row>
    <entry>Header 1</entry>
    <entry>Header 2</entry>
    </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <row>
    <entry>Testing cell 1 text</entry>
    <entry>Testing cell 2</entry>
    </row>
    </tbody>
    </tgroup>
    </table>
    <p name="level_2">Value 3</p>
    <p name="level_2">Value 4</p>
    <p name="level_1">Value 5 note</p>
    <note>Another element</note>
    <p name="level_1">Another Value 1</p>
    <p name="level_2">Another Value 2</p>
    <p name="level_2">Another Value 3 reference</p>
    <reference>Some reference text</reference>
    <p name="level_3">Another Value 4</p>
    <p name="level_3">Another Value 5 example</p>
    <example>Example text goes here</example>
    <p name="level_4">Another Value 3 image</p>
    <image src="./output/media/img(1).jpg"/>
    <p name="level_4">Another Value 4</p>
    <p name="level_1">Another Value 5</p>
    <p name="level_1">Another Value 6</p>
</root>
```

And the desired output should look like:

```
   <root>
    <header>Header text</header>
    <p name="paragraph">Normal Paragraph</p>
    <ol outputclass="ol-level_1 ">
    <li outputclass="li-level_1 ">Value 1</li>
    <li outputclass="li-level_1 ">Value 2 table <table frame="all" 
    rowsep="1" colsep="1"
    id="table_whs_jmk_hzb">
    <title>table1</title>
    <tgroup cols="2" align="center">
    <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="1*"/>
    <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="1*"/>
    <thead>
    <row>
    <entry>Header 1</entry>
    <entry>Header 2</entry>
    </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <row>
    <entry>Testing cell 1 text</entry>
    <entry>Testing cell 2</entry>
    </row>
    </tbody>
    </tgroup>
    </table>
    <ol outputclass="ol-level-2 ">
    <li outputclass="li-level_2 ">Value 3</li>
    <li outputclass="li-level_2 ">Value 4</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li outputclass="li-level_1 ">Value 5 note <note>Another   
    element</note>
    </li>
   <li outputclass="li-level_1 ">Another Value 1 
   <ol outputclass="ol-level-2 ">
   <li outputclass="li-level_2 ">Another Value 2</li>
   <li outputclass="li-level_2 ">Another Value 3 reference 
   <reference>Some reference text</reference>
   <ol outputclass="ol-level-3 ">
   <li outputclass="li-level_3 ">Another Value 4</li>
   <li outputclass="li-level_3 ">Another Value 5 example  
   <example>Example text goes here</example>
   <ol outputclass="ol-level-4 ">
   <li outputclass="li-level_4 ">Another Value 3 image 
   <image src="./output/media/img(1).jpg"/></li>
   <li outputclass="li-level_4 ">Another Value 4</li>
   </ol></li></ol></li></ol></li>
    <li outputclass="li-level_1 ">Another Value 5</li>
    <li outputclass="li-level_1 ">Another Value 6</li>
    </ol></root>
```

And here is the xslt provided by @martin-honnen that I would like modified to get the desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
 exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
 <xsl:param name="items" as="element()*"/>
 <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
 <xsl:for-each-group select="$items" group-starting-with="p[@name = 'level_' || $level]">
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="self::p[@name = 'level_' || $level]">
 <li outputclass="li-{@name}">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 <xsl:where-populated>
 <ol outputclass="ol-level-{$level + 1}">
 <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(tail(current-group()), $level + 1)"/>
 </ol>
 </xsl:where-populated>
 </li>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>
 <xsl:template match="root">
 <root>
 <xsl:copy-of select="header"/>
 <xsl:copy-of select="p[@name = 'paragraph']"/>
 <ol outputclass="ol-level_1 ">
 <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(p[@name = (1 to 6) ! ('level_' || .)], 1)"/>
 </ol>
 </root>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- Templates for note, example, table, and image -->
 <xsl:template match="note | example | table | image">
 <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this adaption of the solution to your previous question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="items" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:variable name="first-level-item" select="$items[self::p[@name = 'level_' || $level]][1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="first-level-item-pos" select="index-of($items/generate-id(), generate-id($first-level-item))"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$items[empty($first-level-item-pos) or position() lt $first-level-item-pos]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$first-level-item">
      <ol outputclass="ol-{$first-level-item/@name}">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$items[position() ge $first-level-item-pos]" group-starting-with="p[@name = 'level_' || $level]">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::p[@name = 'level_' || $level]">
              <li outputclass="li-{@name}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(tail(current-group()), $level + 1)"/>
              </li>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>        
      </ol>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*, 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online fiddle example](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Amf%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmf%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afunction%20name%3D%22mf%3Agroup%22%20as%3D%22node%28%29*%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22items%22%20as%3D%22element%28%29*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22level%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Ainteger%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22first-level-item%22%20select%3D%22%24items%5Bself%3A%3Ap%5B%40name%20%3D%20%27level_%27%20%7C%7C%20%24level%5D%5D%5B1%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22first-level-item-pos%22%20select%3D%22index-of%28%24items%2Fgenerate-id%28%29%2C%20generate-id%28%24first-level-item%29%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%24items%5Bempty%28%24first-level-item-pos%29%20or%20position%28%29%20lt%20%24first-level-item-pos%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22%24first-level-item%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Col%20outputclass%3D%22ol-%7B%24first-level-item%2F%40name%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22%24items%5Bposition%28%29%20ge%20%24first-level-item-pos%5D%22%20group-starting-with%3D%22p%5B%40name%20%3D%20%27level_%27%20%7C%7C%20%24level%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22self%3A%3Ap%5B%40name%20%3D%20%27level_%27%20%7C%7C%20%24level%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20outputclass%3D%22li-%7B%40name%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22mf%3Agroup%28tail%28current-group%28%29%29%2C%20%24level%20%2B%201%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22mf%3Agroup%28current-group%28%29%2C%20%24level%20%2B%201%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fol%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afunction%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22root%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22mf%3Agroup%28*%2C%201%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Croot%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cheader%3EHeader%20text%3C%2Fheader%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22paragraph%22%3ENormal%20Paragraph%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_1%22%3EValue%201%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_1%22%3EValue%202%20table%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20frame%3D%22all%22%20rowsep%3D%221%22%20colsep%3D%221%22%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3D%22table_whs_jmk_hzb%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3Etable1%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctgroup%20cols%3D%222%22%20align%3D%22center%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccolspec%20colname%3D%22c1%22%20colnum%3D%221%22%20colwidth%3D%221*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccolspec%20colname%3D%22c2%22%20colnum%3D%222%22%20colwidth%3D%221*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cthead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Crow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Centry%3EHeader%201%3C%2Fentry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Centry%3EHeader%202%3C%2Fentry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Frow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fthead%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Crow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Centry%3ETesting%20cell%201%20text%3C%2Fentry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Centry%3ETesting%20cell%202%3C%2Fentry%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Frow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftgroup%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_2%22%3EValue%203%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_2%22%3EValue%204%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_1%22%3EValue%205%20note%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cnote%3EAnother%20element%3C%2Fnote%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_1%22%3EAnother%20Value%201%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_2%22%3EAnother%20Value%202%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_2%22%3EAnother%20Value%203%20reference%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Creference%3ESome%20reference%20text%3C%2Freference%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_3%22%3EAnother%20Value%204%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_3%22%3EAnother%20Value%205%20example%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cexample%3EExample%20text%20goes%20here%3C%2Fexample%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_4%22%3EAnother%20Value%203%20image%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cimage%20src%3D%22.%2Foutput%2Fmedia%2Fimg%281%29.jpg%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_4%22%3EAnother%20Value%204%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_1%22%3EAnother%20Value%205%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20name%3D%22level_1%22%3EAnother%20Value%206%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML).

Comment: Thanks a lot @martin-honnen. The code works as expected.